# UINavigationBar show Back button after interrupt swiping right from left edge gesture, how to hide it and why it shown?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

In viewDidLoad, i configure the navigationBar with:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

let backButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "nav_back_normal"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileViewController.backTapped(_:)))

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([backButton], animated: true)
```

and in previous view controller's viewDidAppear,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

And the gesture delegate is :

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count > 1 {
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }
}
```

when i want to swipe right to back to the previous controller, and interrupt, the blue tint Back button shown.
So, why it show and how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I add one line of code to solve this problem in viewDidAppear of current view controller.

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem = nil
```